# Meaning of “jugement”

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Quote from Candide:

> Sa physionomie annonçait son âme. Il avait le jugement assez droit,
>   avec l'esprit le plus simple ; c'est, je crois, pour cette raison
>   qu'on le nommait Candide.

If I understand correctly, this means (loosely translated) something like:

> His face expressed his soul. He got a pretty upright appearance, with
>   a simple mind. That's why, I belive, he was called Candide.

Now I've got some questions:

- Is this correct?
- Is jugement obsolete for describing a person? What is its meaning today, if so?

Comment: He *had* a [straight-forward/righteous](?) intellect, with the simplest spirit. It is, I believe, for this reason that he [was called/they called him] Candide.

Comment: _Complexion_ or _constitution_. It's the _honest simpleton_. This [translation](https://archive.org/stream/candide19942gut/19942.txt) may provide further insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, here *jugement* is synonymous to *thinking ability*, it is described [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jugement) in D.1.

However, this is not used any more outside of philosophy or literature, it has become very outdated in this sense and is now almost always used in the legal sense (A. in CNRTL's article linked above).

Comment: Thanks so far! Would you mind telling me whether the rest of the sentence was translated more or less correct?

Comment: Really? It seems alive and well in Quebec French (and probably North American French in general).

Comment: The phrasing “avoir le jugement droit” is certainly a bit odd. But *jugement* is clearly not outdated. It's alive in France too.